# Reference another workbook with dynamic worksheet name

Tags: excel

I want to reference another workbook and a specific worksheet which is dependent on some cell values.

This equation works

='S:\Down Time[11-Nov_2013_Downtime Tracker.xls]30'!$F$12

but the values 'Nov' and '30' are dynamic-- they depend on the cell values of D13 and E13, respectively.

How can I modify the equation?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this only by excel formulas, you could modify you formula like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'S:\Down Time[11-" & A1 & "_2013_Downtime Tracker.xls]" & A2 & "'!$F$12)
```

In this example it is assumed that the nov-value is in cell `A1` and the 30-value is in cell `A2`. This formula, however, will only work if the referenced workbooks are open. Otherwise the formula would return a `#REF!` error. Only alternative would be to use VBA.

Comment: What prevents it from allowing you to just insert the referenced text?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand that question..?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but here it goes in case someone else is looking for it.
Change the ranges to accommodate your needs.

With VBA:

```
Sub CallOtherWB()

    Dim ThisMonth As String
    Dim TheOtherVar As String

    ThisMonth = Range("D13").Value
    TheOtherVar  = Range("E13").Value

    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "'S:\Down Time[11-" & ThisMonth & "_2013_Downtime Tracker.xls]" & TheOtherVar  & "'!$F$12"
    End With

End Sub
```