# How can I reference other Excel workbooks dynamically via URL?

Tags: excel, url, reference

Trying to wrap my head around this. I have a column of values (dates in mm-dd-yy format ascending). I have another column that pulls a cell value from a workbook on a SharePoint site (there is a unique workbook for each date/row):

```
='http://foo/[mm-dd-yy.xls]worksheet'!$I$5
```

How can I get modify this formula to pull the 'mm-dd-yy' from the values in my first column? For instance A1 contains 01-01-2013 and I want B1 to contain the value from

```
='http://foo/[01.01.2013.xls]worksheet'!$I$5
```

and so on for a large number of rows with dates in column A. I have tried variations of INDIRECT and CONCATENATE with little success. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20412666/2119523. Dynamic reference with excel formulas is not perfect since the workbooks you want to reference to needs to be open in order to get it to work. Depending on what you want to achieve, you might need to do some VBA coding instead.

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I misssed that one when I searched. The workbooks will not be open so it looks like I'll have to go the VBA route. Thanks!